# What does "I don't need to call the horse in the cat does it for me" mean?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

I don't know the meaning of the first sentence in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UArbb.jpg)

> I don't need to call the horse in the cat does it for me
>
> Just a pony running to see her best friend

Answer (score 3):

Informal writing on social media often does not include punctuation.  If you add the standard punctuation, you get:

> I don't need to call the horse in. The cat does it for me.

Comment: As a person who doesn't use social media, it took me a few moments to work out what was meant!